# Google Play Multiplayer: No connection to other players

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I'm currently developing a game using Google Play Multiplayer Services. Everything works fine, e.g. login to Google+, leaderboards and achievements.
Now I try to add a multiplayer function (via the Google Play Games network). My code does not throw any exceptions, it just does not work.
The only `logcat` output from my app is "created" (`private void startQuickGame () {`).

```
public class GameExplorerQuickGame extends Activity implements RoomUpdateListener, RoomStatusUpdateListener {
  private GoogleApiClient client = RXTXChooser.mGoogleApiClient;
  private Room room;
  final static int RC_WAITING_ROOM  = 10002;

  @Override
  public void onCreate (Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);

    if (!this.client.isConnected()) this.client.connect();

    startQuickGame();

  }

  private void startQuickGame () {
    Bundle am = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, 0);

    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
    roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);
    RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();

    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(this.client, roomConfig);
    System.out.println("created");     // printed into logcat
  }

  // create a RoomConfigBuilder that's appropriate for your implementation
  private RoomConfig.Builder makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder () {
    return RoomConfig.builder(this).setMessageReceivedListener(this.googleRxTx).setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onRoomConnected (int statusCode, Room room) {
    this.room = room;
    System.out.println("onRoomConnected");
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
    } else {
        //starting Game Activity...
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void onJoinedRoom (int statusCode, Room room) {
    this.room = room;
    System.out.println("onJoinedRoom");
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
         return;
    }

    Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(this.client, room, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
  }

  @Override
  public void onRoomCreated (int statusCode, Room room) {
    this.room = room;
    System.out.println("onRoomCreated()");
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        return;
    }
    // get waiting room intent
    Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(this.client, room, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
  }
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult (int request, int response, Intent intent) {
    if (request == RC_WAITING_ROOM) {
        if (response == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //starting Game Activity...
        } else if (response == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(this.client, null, this.room.getRoomId());

        } else if (response == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM) {
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(this.client, null, this.room.getRoomId());
        }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectedToRoom (Room arg0) {
    System.out.println("onConnectedToRoom");
    this.room = arg0;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisconnectedFromRoom (Room room) {
    this.room = room;
    System.out.println("onDisconnectedFromRoom");
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(this.client, null, room.getRoomId());
  }
  // are we already playing?
  boolean               mPlaying    = false;

  final static int  MIN_PLAYERS = 2;

  // returns whether there are enough players to start the game
  boolean shouldStartGame (Room room) {
    int connectedPlayers = 0;
    for (Participant p: room.getParticipants()) {
        if (p.isConnectedToRoom()) ++connectedPlayers;
    }
    return connectedPlayers >= MIN_PLAYERS;
  }

  // Returns whether the room is in a state where the game should be canceled.
  boolean shouldCancelGame (Room room) {
    for (Participant p: room.getParticipants()) {
        //          if (!p.isConnectedToRoom()) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPeersConnected (Room room, List<String> peers) {
    System.out.println("onPeersConnected. List.size= " + peers.size());
    if (this.mPlaying) {
    } else if (shouldStartGame(room)) {
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPeersDisconnected (Room room, List<String> peers) {
    this.room = room;
    System.out.println("onPeersDisconnected");
    if (this.mPlaying) {
    } else if (shouldCancelGame(room)) {
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(this.client, null, this.room.getRoomId());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPeerLeft (Room room, List<String> peers) {
    this.room = room;
    System.out.println("onPeerLeft");
    if (!this.mPlaying && shouldCancelGame(room)) {
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(this.client, null, this.room.getRoomId());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPeerDeclined (Room room, List<String> peers) {
    this.room = room;
    if (!this.mPlaying && shouldCancelGame(room)) {
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(this.client, null, this.room.getRoomId());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onP2PConnected (String arg0) {
    System.out.println("onP2PConnected");
  }

  @Override
  public void onP2PDisconnected (String arg0) {
    System.out.println("onP2PDisconnected");
  }
  @Override
  public void onPeerInvitedToRoom (Room arg0, List<String> arg1) {
    System.out.println("onPeerInvitedRoom");
    this.room = arg0;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPeerJoined (Room arg0, List<String> arg1) {
    System.out.println("onPeerJoined");
    this.room = arg0;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRoomAutoMatching (Room arg0) {
    System.out.println("onRoomAutoMatching");
    this.room = arg0;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRoomConnecting (Room arg0) {
    System.out.println("onRoomCeonnecting");
    this.room = arg0;
  }

  @Override
  public void onLeftRoom (int arg0, String arg1) {
    System.out.println("onLeftRoom");
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a ton of code for someone to read in order to help solve your issue.  Can you narrow down your code to the problematic area?

Comment: I tried. But I'm not sure where the origin of the problem is...

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution!

I forgot to add on line:

    `private void startQuickGame () {
    //skipping some lines...
        RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
        roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(am);
        roomConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this); //I forgot this line
        RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
    //skipping some lines...
}`

And the googleAPIClient was logged out for some strange reason